# DoubleClick For Publishers and Non Profit Group Approval

Tags: google-dfp

Has anyone tried to get approval for DFP as a non profit with a lot of content?  There is nothing in google's policies preventing use of DFP or showing ads as a non profit but they do want you to have an adsense account to get approval.  However, many non profits have google grants which prevents you from having adsense hence stopping the sign up form process:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/GmdyYA6oGpY;context-place=topicsearchin/dfp/grant$20adsense

Policy that non profits can run ads:
https://support.google.com/nonprofits/answer/171852?hl=en&vid=0-1176304901161-1508793530395

Thanks.